# Site navigation top link bar: max number of dynamic items not respecting the sort order

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation, quick-launch

I'm using a publishing site. I configured the top navigation link bar to show **max 20 dynamic items** and set the sort order to **Sort automatically by last modified date in descending order**.

The problem is that in the Navigation Editing and Sorting section, I can see all the pages (they are 23 in total) sorted correctly, with the most recent on top. On the menu though, the 20 pages shown don't respect the sort order as the 21st, 22nd and 23rd pages (which are the most recent ones) don't show up.

Any idea on what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Please change the "Maximum number of dynamic items to show within this level of navigation" from 20 to 0 and check the results.

Comment: This does seem to solve the sorting issue, but obviously it is now showing all the pages, whereas I want to limit them to 20.